# Loop not working in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a database with multiple questionnaires, each questionnaire has related (multiplechoice) questions, and each question has related answers.

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will delete all questions and related answers with only the ID of the questionnaire.
My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteQuestionnnaire] 

    @EnqueteID bigint
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @QID bigint

    DECLARE questionCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT ID FROM questions WHERE EnqueteID = @EnqueteID

    OPEN questionCursor;

    FETCH questionCursor INTO @QID  

    WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)
    BEGIN

    -- this is not working correct, the related answers are NOT being deleted

        FETCH questionCursor INTO @QID
        DELETE FROM answers WHERE QuestionID=@QID

    END

    CLOSE questionCursor

        --  this works fine, the questions are being deleted
    DELETE FROM questions WHERE EnqueteID=@EnqueteID

END
```

the related questions are being deleted but the related answers not, so I'm doing something wrong in my loop, is there anybody out there who sees what it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: switching fetch and delete might help?

Comment: You know this isn't the right way to do it, right?  You can just write one delete statement to delete the answers and join it on the the results you want to delete instead of using the cursor.  `DELETE FROM a FROM answers a JOIN questions q on a.QuestionID = q.ID WHERE q.EnqueteID = @EnqueteID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cursor is slightly odd, in that `FETCH NEXT` is usually the last statement in the loop (see the example from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx)), so in fact the first value you fetch is immediately replaced by the second one. Adding some `PRINT` statements into the cursor to check the current value of `@QID` would show this.

But the real answer is not to use a cursor at all, it's unnecessary here:

```
delete from dbo.answers where questionid in (
    select questionid from dbo.questions where EnqueteID = @EnqueteID
)
delete from dbo.questions where EnqueteID = @EnqueteID
```

Comment: Thanks Pondfile! this is obviously the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The overall cursor looks good. I'd move the fetch statement (within the loop) to the bottom right before the end. Currently you're fetching the first value into the parameter, then fetching the second value as soon as you enter the loop; effectively tossing out the first value while never using it.

```
WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)
BEGIN

    --SELECT @QID and Answers to see if you're getting the right values
    SELECT @QID
    SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE QuestionID = @QID
    -- DELETE FROM answers WHERE QuestionID=@QID

    --Fetch should be right before the loop ends
    FETCH questionCursor INTO @QID   
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching in the first and then the second so the first does not get deleted

```
FETCH questionCursor INTO @QID  

WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM answers WHERE QuestionID=@QID
    FETCH questionCursor INTO @QID

END
```

or

```
delete answers 
where QuestionID in (select SELECT ID FROM questions WHERE EnqueteID = @EnqueteID);
go
delete questions WHERE EnqueteID = @EnqueteID;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the looping issue. I did use Pondfiles solution because as he says Looping isn't neccessary here.